# angular2 ng2-smart-table :issue while catch the data from custom button event

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have been gone through ng2-smart table ,I have created columns as mentioned in document for achieving the functionality on column cell
 I have followed below link 
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/custom-edit-view/basic-example-button-view.component.ts

But I am unable to catch the event which has mentioned in ButtonViewComponent in other components.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewCell } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import {Routes, RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
@Component({
    selector: 'button-view',
    template: `
    <a (click)="onClick()">{{ renderValue }}</a>
  `,
})
export class ButtonViewComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {
    renderValue: string;

    @Input() value: string | number = '';
    @Input() rowData: any='Hello';

    @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() sendInformationTOANI: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
    constructor(private router: Router){

    }
    onClick() {
        this.save.emit(this.rowData);
        console.log('emit data');
// Here i want to catch this event in other component!!
    }


}
```

@Note: I have tried using @Input and @Output but still not able to catch event
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have declared your columns in the Parent Component, you can access your child component's event using **onComponentInitFunction()** function. For instance

```
{
  title: "Actions",
  type: "custom",
  renderComponent: ButtonViewComponent,
  onComponentInitFunction :(instance) => {
    instance.save.subscribe(row => {
     //now you can access value from child component here
  });
 }
};
```